# Infinite sum of delta function when calculating Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta, periodic-functions

I am trying to find the Fourier Transform of the periodic function

$$ f (\theta) = \sum_{n=- \infty}^{\infty} a_n \space \exp(i n \theta)$$.

Using the formula, $$ f(k) = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} d \theta \space  \exp(-ik \theta ) f(\theta)$$

I get the following infinite sum $ 2 \pi a_n \sum_{n=- \infty}^{\infty} \space  \delta (k - n)$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Do you really get two $2\pi a_n$s?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown sorry typo, edited

Comment: Did you remove the correct $a_n$?

Comment: I believe the $a_n$ should be inside the last sum. Other than that, what you've done is correct.

Comment: How did you define the Fourier transform of a non-$L^1$ nor $L^2$ function such as $\exp(in \theta)$. Also what is the Fourier transform of $\sum_n a_n \delta(k-n)$ ?

Comment: [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb).